# Pacbio HIFI pbmm2 alignment metrics

Tags: sequence-alignment, pacbio

I am new to pacbio sequencing data. I just did some alignment of pacbio HiFI data using pbmm2. I have the bam now, I would like to collect some metrics on the alignment. I used to work on the illumina data, I used picard CollectAlignmentSummaryMetrics, CollectGcBiasMetrics, CollectInsertSizeMetrics to collect a series of alignment metrics.
I was wondering if there is similar tools for pacbio data. I searched and did not find an answer.

We are mainly interested in aligned rate, sequence length, coverage, accuracy, and GC content. So I write some scripts for it. These scripts are inside the nextflow, the input is the bam file

```
samtools flagstat $bam \
 | head -8 \
 | tr " " ","  \
 | tr "+" " " \
 | awk -F',' '{ print $1, $3}' \
 | paste - - - - - - - -  \
 | awk '{print $1, $3, $5, $7, $9, $11, $2, $4, $6, $8, $10, $12 }' >  align_prp
 
 samtools depth $bam \
 |  awk '{sum+=$3; sumsq+=$3*$3} END { print sum/NR, sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}' > coverage
 
 samtools view $bam \
 | awk '{ $35=length($10); sum+=$35; sumsq+=$35*$35} END { print sum/NR, sqrt(sumsq/NR - (sum/NR)**2)}' > length
 

 
 samtools view  $bam \
 | cut -f 10 \
 | fold -w 1 \
 | awk '($1=="G" || $1=="C") {N++;} END {print (N/(1.0*NR)*100);}' > GC_content
```

But I am still interested to know if there are some package available there.

Comment: Is this useful at all? https://www.biostars.org/p/9494195/

Comment: No, I am not accessible to Revio, Sequel II and IIe systems.